# What kind of array is this in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, arduino, lcd

I notice that this is a C++ array, but I do not know what it is storing and how. I used an Arduino Image Converter. I forgot the source, but I remember that it was to convert images to be displayed on Arduino TFT screens. Could someone give me a hint to what the name of the encoding is or whatever it is, so I can research it further: (BTW this is only an excerpt of the code.)

```
// Generated by  : ImageConverter 565 v1.1
// Generated from: 4-14-12-063-copy.jpg
// Time generated: 5/8/2016 12:57:28 PM
// Dimensions    : 484x324 pixels
// Size          : 313,632 Bytes

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

prog_uint16_t 4-14-12-063-copy[0x26490] PROGMEM ={
0xC638, 0xD6B9, 0xC617, 0xC637, 0x844F, 0xA573, 0x7C8F, 0xC6B8, 0xFFDD, 0xEF3B, 0xCDF6, 0x9C2F, 0x838D, 0x51E6, 0x4A47, 0x4A67,   // 0x0010 (16)
0x7BCD, 0xB5B5, 0xCE37, 0xA513, 0xC637, 0xCE57, 0xBD75, 0x5249, 0x3184, 0x4A47, 0x736D, 0x83EF, 0x39E6, 0x2123, 0x2923, 0x18E2,   // 0x0020 (32)
0x2122, 0x2963, 0x1902, 0x18E1, 0x2964, 0x4247, 0x2984, 0x2122, 0x31A4, 0x39E5, 0x2964, 0x2964, 0x3164, 0x18A1, 0x18A1, 0x2943,   // 0x0030 (48)
0x31A5, 0x18C1, 0x10C1, 0x0880, 0x18E2, 0x1902, 0x10A1, 0x10A1, 0x10A1, 0x0880, 0x08A0, 0x1102, 0x1923, 0x10E2, 0x1081, 0x0860,   // 0x0040 (64)
0x0040, 0x0860, 0x08A1, 0x0881, 0x0880, 0x0880, 0x0880, 0x18E2, 0x18C2, 0x0020, 0x0860, 0x0840, 0x0020, 0x0020, 0x0000, 0x0040,   // 0x0050 (80)
0x0040, 0x08A0, 0x31E5, 0xA5B4, 0xA5B4, 0x9512, 0x5B8B, 0x3A87, 0x21C4, 0x2A25, 0x3246, 0x5B8B, 0x8CB0, 0x638C, 0x42A8, 0x4AC9,   // 0x0060 (96)
0x532A, 0x52E9, 0x4AC8, 0x7C4E, 0xA594, 0xADB4, 0x94D1, 0x73CD, 0x842F, 0x73CD, 0x7C4F, 0x740E, 0xB5F6, 0xE75C, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,   // 0x0070 (112)
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,   // 0x0080 (128)
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,   // 0x0090 (144)
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,   // 0x00A0 (160)
```

Comment: This is not valid C++ code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking an unclear question, claiming that something is C++ that is not syntactically valid in C++.

Comment: The comments tell you what file it was generated from and what program generated it.

Comment: Also it was generated today - have you forgotten what you did already?

Comment: If you google the filename you can find the original picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `4-14-12-063-copy` is not a valid variable/type name in C++, and array declarations goes like

```
typename  nameofarry[sizeofarry] = { optional initializer block };
```

So the `PROGMEM` after the `[]` is not valid C++ either, and if it compiles at all it must be some kind of non-standard extension specifically for embedded programming.

however if what you looking for is the word "hexadecimal" then the data looks like 16-bit hexadecimal data which would correspond with what looks like the intended type of `prog_uint16_t` -- which presumably is a unsigned 16 bit integer.

Update: ... And according to the comment in the code, the data is generated from a [JPEG image](http://www.sdbsoccer.com/4-14-12-063-copy/).

Comment: I was going to write my own answer but, you might as well add that - according to the code's comments - it's a jpeg.

Comment: The data isn't a JPEG image. It was generated from a JPEG image but is now another format.

Comment: @interjay -- sure, updated the wording